# What is the mongodb server url for meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using PhpStorm editor with mongoDB plugin, I was wondering what should be the mongodb server url,so I could monitor my mongoDB's activities directly from PhpStorm[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running MongoDB using the meteor command line you can access the database at localhost:3001. The database name is meteor and there is no need for credentials.

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you set `MONGO_URL`. If you run `meteor` locally with out setting `MONGO_URL` try

> mongo localhost:3001/meteor

If you have deployed your app to `meteor.com` try

> meteor mongo yourapp.meteor.com --url

This will return the `MONGO_URL`so that you can monitor/backup/restore your DB. Eg

> mongodb://client-lots-of-numers@production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/yourapp_meteor_com